# Genshi if else statement

Tags: genshi

I have been try ot get genshi py:if to work with python expression.
To make things simple I try the following code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/">
  <body>
    <py:if test = ${len(linstoflinks)>0}>
      <p>List has lenght</p>
    </py:if>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the Genshi docs they say I can put any python expressions
as long I put my expression in curly braces with a dollar sign in front.
http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/GenshiTutorial.
I even try

```
<py:if test = "${True}">
<py:if test = "${1==1}">
```

This simple code does not work. error is : not well formed (invalid token)
This works

```
<py:if test = "foo">
```

Anyone has any idea how I can make this if statement work with python expression.
Thanks

Comment: any points wiki or womething???

Answer (score 1):

You don't need curly braces inside template directives.

try this

```
<py:if test="len(linstoflinks)>0">
```